# File operation error: eacces. Target:../ebin. Function: list_dir. Process: application_controller. on ejjabberd server

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am getting an error as follow:

File operation error: eacces. Target: /opt/ejabberd-16.03/lib/xmerl-1.3.7/ebin. Function: list_dir. Process: application_controller.

On AWS server but it is working locally.Further it was working in the past but now its not working..

Answer (score 0):

It means ejabberd does not have access to the target repository. You have an installation issue. Fix your Linux directory access rights.